# merge creating extra rows?

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge two dataframes by row names. But when I try the following code, it creates extra rows in the merged data `merged['NA',]` which are all `NA`.

```
merged <- merge(control, counts, by=0) #merge by rows
rownames(merged) <- merged[, 1] # assign rownames
merged <- merged[, -1] # delete column with rownames
```

After executing the above code. There is a row of `'NA'` in the `merged` variable with all `NA` values : `merged['NA',]`

Why is this ? Can someone tell me how to fix this please ?

Here are the dataframe samples:

```
> control

           BNK_spBM1_L1_bar25 BNK_spBM1_L1_bar26 BNK_spBM1_L1_bar27
OR4F5                       0                  0                  0
FO538757.3                  0                  0                  0
FO538757.2                  0                  0                  0
OR4F29                      0                  0                  0
OR4F16                      0                  0                  0
```

```
>counts

          AAACCTGCACATCTTT-1 AAACCTGCATTCCTCG-1 AAACCTGGTTAGAACA-1
DDX11L1                    0                  0                  0
WASH7P                     0                  0                  0
MIR6859-1                  0                  0                  0
MIR1302-2                  0                  0                  0
FAM138A                    0                  0                  0
```

But `merged` gives me NA values instead of giving `subscript out of bounds` error.

```
> merged['NA',]
   Row.names BNK_spBM1_L1_bar25 BNK_spBM1_L1_bar26 BNK_spBM1_L1_bar27
NA      <NA>                 NA                 NA                 NA
   AAACCTGCACATCTTT-1 AAACCTGCATTCCTCG-1 AAACCTGGTTAGAACA-1
NA                 NA                 NA                 NA
```

Comment: Can you please share a few rows of data to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @GregorThomas the variable merged contains a row with name 'NA' which has all NA values in it. although neither control nor counts has any row named 'NA'

Comment: Yes, I understand that that's the problem you're facing. But without sample data I have nothing to run your code on that reproduces the problem. This makes it very hard to investigate what is going on and test possible solutions. Could you please share a few rows of data to demonstrate the problem? The easiest way to share sample data with with `dput()` as it makes copy/pasteable versions of R objects including all data structure info. e.g. `dput(control[1:5, 1:3])` for the first 5 rows and 3 columns of `control`. Pick rows that that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @GregorThomas added the data matrices as well!

Comment: You are merging the "control" and "counts" data.frames by their row.names but none of the row names match so the result of the call to `merge()` is a data.frame with 0 rows.

Comment: And looking for a row named `'NA'` generally returns a `NA` row as you show. See, e.g, `mtcars['NA', ]`. No "subscript out of bounds" error. This is generally true for data frame rows, same result with `mtcars['hello', ]` or `mtcars[500, ]`.